# Change pnotify encoding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, web-frontend, pnotify

I want to change the encoding of pnotify's notifications into UTF-8.

The pnotify version I'm currently using is 2.0.1.

As far as I know, pnotify is an already deprecated npm module but it's what has been used in the ongoing project that I was assigned to develop for. I'm open to alternative packages, although I'd rather avoid changing the npm dependencies if I could.

Would I need to change something in the module itself, or is there a way to specify the encoding without having to hack something in `node_modules`?

Thanks in advance.